# Convert SQL Server database to SQL Server CE?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, compact-framework, sql-server-ce

I have a SQL Server database which I can read from, is there a quick way I can turn it into an SQL Server CE database through C# or will I have to read in all the data then output it in SQL Server CE.

Comment: Really depends on what your current database has, and uses -- some stuff isn't supported in CE.

Comment: so what have you tried? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25685/SQL-Server-to-SQL-Server-Compact-Edition-Database or http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use my SQL Server Compact scripting API, which will allow you to export a Server database to a script file, and run the resulting file against a SQL Server Compact database from your C# code. http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Scripting%20API%20samples&referringTitle=Documentation